# Subscribe to Mailchimp list by REST API / GET request

Tags: javascript, rest, curl, mailchimp

How to easily, with a single HTTP request, add an email to a MailChimp subscribers list? Just from a command line with `curl` or from within a browser with, for example, `new Image().src = '…'`.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
curl 'http://{LOGIN}.{DATACENTER}.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u={USER_ID}&id={LIST_ID}&EMAIL={SUBSCRIBER}'
```

Add more *MERGE* fields by appending get parameters like this:

```
curl 'http://{LOGIN}.{DATACENTER}.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u={USER_ID}&id={LIST_ID}&EMAIL={SUBSCRIBER}&MERGE1=value&MERGE2=value2'
```

#### What about LOGIN, DATACENTER, u, id?

- **LOGIN** is the MailChimp account name;
- **DATACENTER** is just a DC the endpoint is located in;
- **u** is the user ID;
- **id** is the subscribers list ID.

Mailchimp docs advice to get these values by ripping them out of an embedded form HTML code.

For me, the form code looks like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kung-fu-tzu/72539aed64d1a4598856), and the corresponding URI looks like this:

```
http://inshaker.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3750251e6abbbabf6c38f93bf&id=dded750b1a&EMAIL=a@b.c
```

**NOTE**: This is *not* an API call. Mailchimp API is based on JSON-RPC and is a bit harder to use from the command line or client-side JS.